# How to open any eclipse Wizard from Intro Page in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I use HTML file for my welcome page. I want to open Eclipse Wizard from intro page using

```
href="http://org.eclipse.ui.intro/runAction?pluginId=MobileTalk&amp;class=mobiletalk.intro.ShowPerspectiveIntroAction"
```

In the class `ShowPerspectiveIntroAction`, my code as follows:

```
Class c = Class.forName("tttt.ddt.plugin.project.NewTtttProjectWizard");
Wizard wizard = (Wizard) c.newInstance();
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(),wizard);
dialog.open();
```

But I get the error: `classnotfound:tttt.ddt.plugin.project.NewTtttProjectWizard`

how can I open any Eclipse Wizard from intro page correctly?

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your code I suspect it is a class loader issue. Using Class.forName is not a safe practice in Eclipse/OSGI because each plugin/bundle uses their own class loader and as a result a lot of times Class Not Found Exceptions happen. A better approach is to get the Bundle/Plugin that contains your wizard class by doing this: Platform.getBundle("com.stackoverflow.myplugindId"), that returns an instance of Bundle. Then on the instance of bundle call the .loadClass("tttt.ddt.plugin.project.NewTtttProjectWizard") which will use the correct class loader and then once you have an instance of the Class you can call the newInstance() method which will resolve your Class not found issue. Hope that helps, class loading is more complex in an OSGI environment because every plugin has its own class loader for security reasons so I advise against using Class.forName in your code. - Duncan

Comment: thanks! it works, but after i create a new project according to the eclipse wizard, i click "finish", the wizard is not close. when i use the eclipse wizard to create a project in the plugin itself, it works well.
here is the exception:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-11-06 11:10:20.701
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at tttt.ddt.plugin.project.NewTtttProjectWizard.performFinish(NewTtttProjectWizard.java:130)

Comment: the code is :
getWorkbench().getWorkingSetManager().addToWorkingSets(proj,
    workingSets);  // line 130

@Duncan Krebs

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Not sure if your Wizard extends NewProject wizard. I would suggest adding a breakpoint for NPE and see what is null and go from there. Either stop at NPE or the first line in performFinish() of your wizard. - Duncan